# Showing all data from mysql big database table using bootstrap dynamic table

Tags: database, performance, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, query-optimization

I am working on a project using codeigniter and bootstrap twitter. But I am little worried about database for showing all data . I am using MySQL database.I have a product table. Everyday there are adding more than thousand products with different product status.

And I am using bootstrap dynamic table for showing all products with pagination.It is good for searching any products,also for pagination.But in query I am not using limit .So it is taking so much time for loading all products into my web site.If it is going like that then it will be a great problem for my web site.Now I don’t understand which steps I will take.

It will be nice if I get some best solution for solving these types of problems.
Please give me some advice and solution.

Comment: For big data results, the optimal way is to retrieve the data only if required. E.g: Use AJAX for loading the next data set into the table when the user click on next button on pagination.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.Its okay.But how can i handle search option like dynamic table search option.Or you have any idea about any js library file which is related with this.@equisde

Comment: Yep. [**Datatables**](http://www.datatables.net/) is a very nice plugin for jQuery for that. There are a lot of examples on the docs. Also [**for AJAX**](http://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap) even [**working with Bootstrap**](http://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap)